# Comm/Diff (or alternative) that respects glob characters: is this possible?

Tags: bash, diff

Restricting "globbing" grammar to, specifically, suffix-globbing, `*` characters only, suppose I have:

```
// foo.txt
foo.*
biz

// bar.txt
bar
foo.bar
```

And I would like to write:

```
diff <(sort -u foo) <(sort -u bar)

# alternatively
comm -3 <(sort -u foo) <(sort -u bar)
```

Such that it returns:

```
# diff
> bar
< biz

# comm
bar 
biz
```

Is this possible natively?

Comment: Would regex also be fine, or needs to be glob?

Comment: @pLumo regex will get the job done for now, but glob I think would be the simplest and most usable.

Comment: If the first file the template and the other one the data, or should wildcard in the second one also be considered?

Comment: If `bar.txt`  contains both `foo.bar` and `foo.baz`, what should be the outcome?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas for my use case, internal sorting is ok -- does not have to duplicate diff, just the actual expression there -- and it should be globbing.  So you'll need to drop a `.*` in there for the `*`s to simulate globbing with a regex

Answer (score 2):

If you want to report all the lines of `bar.txt` that match none of the patterns in `foo.txt`, in `zsh`, that could be:

```
unique_lines=(${(fu)"$(<bar.txt)"})
unique_patterns=(${(fu)"$(<foo.txt)"})
pattern="(${(j[|])unique_patterns})"

print -rC1 -- ${unique_lines:#$~pattern}
```

Or all in one go:

```
print -rC1 -- ${${(fu)"$(<bar.txt)"}:#(${(j[|])~${(fu)"$(<foo.txt)"}})}
```

- `$(<file)` is the ksh-like operator that expands to contents of `$file` striped of trailing newline characters.
- `${(flags)param}` uses *parameter expansion flags* to affect the `param` expansion.
- `f` flag, splits on linefeeds (here expands to the list of non-empty lines).
- `u` (uniq): removes duplicates. So `${(fu)"$(<foo.txt)"}` expands to the unique non-empty lines of `foo.txt`
- `${array:#pattern}` expands to the elements of `$array` that don't match the pattern. Here the pattern is constructed as:
- `${(j[|])unique_patterns}` where the elements of `$unique_patterns` are joined with `|`. So we end up with a `(line1|line2|...)` pattern.
- The `~` in `$~pattern` causes wildcards to be considered as such upon the variable expansion.

Note that wildcard syntax is that of `zsh` wildcards. That's affected by a few shell options like `extendedglob`, `kshglob`, `nocasematch`...

In `bash`, you could do something similar with:

```
shopt -s extglob
pattern="@($(sort -u foo.txt | paste  -sd '|' -))"
sort -u bar.txt |
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ $line = $pattern ]] || printf '%s\n' "$line"
  done
```

This time, the syntax is that of bash extglob wildcards, similar to that of ksh88 ones.

Note that the order of the lines in `bar.txt` ends up being changed.

Comment: can you explain what each of these nestings are doing, and what they are calling? also, am in bash

Comment: @Christopher, in `bash`, just  wrap that code in `zsh -c '...'`, but why would you want to use `bash`?

Comment: this seems to be O(n^pattern count), or is it pretty quick?

Comment: @Christopher, more like in `O(n*pattern count)` though that depends on how likely the lines are to match the patterns (and the order of patterns as they will be tried in order). See edit for a bash solution, but note that bash pattern matching is notoriously inefficient.

Comment: yeah, O(n*pattern count) is right. my mistake.  but there is no linear solution using the built-in unix tools? (i.e., the compiled binaries)

Comment: I didn't give it much thought, but I'm not sure how you can avoid trying each pattern against each line (until one matches).

Comment: yeah, I guess there is a missing tool there.

Comment: @Christopher, what I mean is that that *tool* would likely have to try each pattern against each line anyway. Unless there's a way to do it otherwise, that tool is probably not *missing* that much as it can be done with shells as I've shown or relatively easily with `perl`/`ruby`/`python` and their `fnmatch()` APIs.

Comment: I'll post what I am doing later.  The problem is sorting glob strings in with regular strings, and restricting your grammar such that a sorted difference works.  It is basically a restriction of general globbing to suffix globbing only.   This grammar can be compared linearly.  I suppose I could do more general globbing by implementing a custom string value comparison.  But, I don't need to do that yet.

Comment: How do you sort `ab`, `?b`, `cb`, `[b-z]b`?

Comment: I am in python, at the moment. -- whatever python's sort is, I'll be restricting myself to suffix only globs.

Comment: @Christopher, if your wildcards have additional constraints (for instance that `*` is the only wildcard in use and that it's only found at the end of the pattern), you may want to add that information to your question.

Comment: updated, per your rec.